# Iso-compliant conversion

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new in django and I'm still bit confused with something written in documentation. 
I'm using django 1.8 with python 2. 
Reading this paragraph [about saving an object in db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save), I got puzzled reading this:

> For example, DateField fields use a Python datetime object to store
>   data. Databases don’t store datetime objects, so the field value must
>   be converted into an ISO-compliant date string for insertion into the
>   database.

Online I found very different ways to do this, but actually I really don't understand how to convert an ISO-Compliant date string!

Furthermore, in my database I've DateTimeField, DateField, TimeField... how can I do this convertion to save new objects in my db?

Thank you!

Edit:
model

```
class CommunityList (models.Model):

      id_community = models.UUIDField (primary_key=True)
      data_creation = models.DateField 
      subcommunity_flag = models.BooleanField
```

I'm importing the data from a file. 
This is the full traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Community/CommunityApp/CommunityList

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'CommunityApp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/DjangoProjects/Community/CommunityApp/views.py" in import_data
  108.                    CommunityList(datareader)
File "/home/DjangoProjects/Community/CommunityApp/views.py" in CommunityList
  80.             subcommunity_flag=row['subcommunity_flag']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  480.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /Community/CommunityApp/CommunityList
Exception Value: 'data_creation' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: You have posted this question an then disappeared!

Comment: I'm actually working on another project, sorry. I will answer ASAP.

Comment: At the end the only way to store data in my db was using this function [https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat] and the store the output in the db.

Answer (score 1):

I think you skimmed over the first part of that page in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save).

> What happens when you save?
>
> When you save an object, **Django performs** the following steps:

Emphasis mine. There is no need for you to do any conversions yourself.

Comment: Actually, there is clearly written that simple data types are 'ready to write' but: 
**However, more complex data types often require some modification** and then there is the part I already quoted. I do need do to that conversion, because I receive an error because I don't.

Comment: If you have recieved an error your question should have contained it

Comment: Yes,you're right. I'm learning just now, I add this to the post.

Comment: please fix the typo in your models and please add the relevent section of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing at all to do with field conversion.

Your model does not actually include the `data_creation` or `subcommunity_flag` fields, because you did not call the field classes in your model definition.

```
  data_creation = models.DateField()
  subcommunity_flag = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: It was my typo, really,now I try to save the new istance deleting the 'data_creation' Fields, and... it actually saves it. The problem is still in the DateField. 
Why in the docs is written to make an Iso-Compliant conversion if I don't need to do?

Comment: As e4c5 already answered, it says that is what *Django* does, not what you do. Now, if you are getting a different error, **you should post it**.